# DNS questio in windows DNS 2008 r2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

If I want to use specific DNS servers i.e my ISP DNS or Opendns  etc, for external resolution. Do I set that under the DNS server properties under "**Forwarders**" or on the NIC of my DC. To add to my confusion, under my domain zone properties it has a "**Name Servers"** tab. Ive set that to internal servers. I threw that in here in case I misunderstood that section. My current set up works but i want to better understand what it is that I did to make it work.

Comment: asked for a reason. if google could answer it all this place wouldn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You put the external DNS In the forwarder tab please, and in the DC NIC you set the ip of your server, or the loopback ip only

Comment: thanks for the response. to add to my understating if i do a interactive nslookup and set debug switch. should i see the external dns when resolving yahoo.com etc ? right ?

Comment: @ssvegeta96 debug switch? no idea never used that, but it mean your dns server will lookup on its forwarders and will cache the result to serve other PC. Unlike a simple lookup on the nic that would be cached for the server only

Comment: Thank you for the info and this is what i was referring to. kinda cool and less of a hassle than running a packet capture.albeit less detailed.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490733.aspx